# Unmarshall list into set

Tags: arrays, go, data-structures, set

Moved from python to golang:

```
jsonBlob := `{ "test" : {"thing":["team1", "team2"]}}`

type other map[string]Myset
type stuff map[string]other
type MySet struct {
    set mapset.Set
}

//Custom unmarshaller
func (s *MySet) UnmarshalJSON(p []byte) error {
    var a []interface{}
    if err := json.Unmarshal(p, &a); err != nil {
        return err
    }
    s.set = mapset.NewSet(a)
    return nil
}

 // Unmarshall it
 var s stuff
 err := json.Unmarshall(jsonBlob, &s)
 if err != nil {
  return err   
}
```

**but it throws: runtime error: hash of unhashable type []interface {}**

Comment: @Himanshu please see it is in the code as var jsonBlob :)

Comment: The `mapset.Set` type doesn't have an `UnmarshalJSON` method, and there's no real reason for it to have one, since there's is no "set" type in json.

Comment: Also note that `mapset.Set` is an interface, and you can't unmarshal into an interface without providing a concrete value to use.

Comment: @JimB Thanks for the suggestion.I am struggling with converting that.Do you have a suggestion how can i achieve the array to set conversion in go lang?

Comment: As @JimB stated already there are no sets in Golang why you need to convert a value into a set like python set. If it is related to any particular requirement then you can think of any other data structure given by Go

Comment: @Himanshu because array will keep growing exponentially and doing intersection and search operation on array would become inefficient , that's why i thought of using Set or map might be good idea.

Comment: So you can use `map`. In Golang there are no sets

Comment: @immrsteel: Looking at the docs for the package you linked, you can convert a slice to a that Set type using the provided constructors, e.g. [`NewSet`](https://godoc.org/github.com/deckarep/golang-set#NewSet), or just add the items individually.

Comment: @Himanshu: I can't speak for the quality of the referenced package, but there's nothing wrong with using a "set" type if you need convenient "set" operations (and whether they are needed or not here, I also can't say)

Comment: @JimB yeah i read that in docs but are you suggesting i should unmarshall givev json into array instead of set and then type cast array into set?

Comment: @immrsteel: Yes, you need to start by unmarshaling the values into a _slice_ (not an array), because that is the native type that a json array unmarshals into.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that the data type you wish to use is an interface, and does not satisfy the [json.Unmarshaler](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Unmarshaler) interface, you have two options:

1. Unmarshal to an array, then convert to your preferred type.
2. Create a custom type, that wraps your preferred type, and provides an `UnmarshalJSON` method. This is functionally the same as #1, but may be easier to use.  Example:

   ```
   type MySet struct {
       set mapset.Set
   }

   func (s *MySet) UnmarshalJSON(p []byte) error {
       var a []interface{}
       if err := json.Unmarshal(p, &a); err != nil {
           return err
       }
       s.set = mapset.NewSet(a)
       return nil
   }
   ```

   (Note, this code is untested; it is not meant to be a complete solution, but a guide in the right direction.)

Comment: thanks for the example but wouldn't that will going to unmarshall the whole json into a set instead of unmarshalling only array

Comment: No. That method will only get the JSON fragment specific to the specific entity. i.e. if you're unmarshaling `{"foo":1, "bar": [1,2,3]}` into `struct{Foo int, Bar *MySet}`, the above function will be called with the input `[1,2,3]`.

Comment: I tried to use the custom marshaller(edited in question) but it throws  runtime error: hash of unhashable type []interface {}

Comment: It would seem you need to use a hashable type, then, rather than []interface{}. But since I don't know your input data, I cannot tell you which type to use.

Comment: This is my jsonBlob := `{ "test" : {"thing":["team1", "team2"]}}` and i edited the code on how i am using the customer marshaller. can you please take a look?

Comment: It was from mapset.NewSet(a) changing it to mapset.NewSetFromSlice(a) fixed it.Thanks

Comment: Flimzy It prints out &map[test:map[thing:{nil} ] .It never writes down actual value. I beleive this might not be the right way of assigning the value .   "type other map[string]Myset"